# Reading heat map at point in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, layers, overlay, heat-map

I have created a set of heatmaps based on the amount of certain chemicals released at specific sites in an area using the QGIS heatmap plugin. I now have a CSV of patient locations that I have overlayed onto this map.

I want to be able to read off the individual raster value (color/chemical concentration) for every patient at their exact location and be able to export this for analysis.

How can I do this?

Additionally, I have heatmaps for almost 100 different chemicals so would it be possible to overlay all of the heatmaps and get an individual value for each chemical that could be appended to a new row on the patient attribute table?

If this is too difficult or not possible that is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this tutorial,
**QGIS 3.x: Processing Toolbox / Raster analysis / Sample raster values algorithm**
https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/sampling_raster_data.html